# Does this XML format look ok?

Tags: xml

I received an xml file from someone and I'm having a hard time trying to process it (using an ETL tool).  I don't have much experience dealing with xml files so I'm wondering if this xml format is normal and I just need to somehow translate it.  I'm having trouble because there are multiple property tags for each item.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

-Chris

```
<items>
  <item name="itemA">
    <property propertyName="color">
      <value>Red</value>
    </property>
    <property propertyName="shape">
      <value>Circle</value>
    </property>
    <property propertyName="age">
      <value>20</value>
    </property>
  </item>
  <item name="itemB">
  ...
  </item>
</items>
```

Ideally, I'd like to see this:

```
<item name="itemA">
  <color>Red</color><shape>Circle</shape><age>20</age>
</item>
```

Comment: It's valid and it's well-formed - it has a single root-level node, none of the nodes are "open-ended", none of the nodes are "intertwined" (opening and closing tags not in order) or anything else... looks like pretty solid XML to me, yes.

Comment: Would it be easier if you transform the first type of XML into the second using XSLT?

Comment: @marc_s: Valid against what schema/DTD?

Comment: @Dabbler I think he means valid by the [xml official spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

Comment: @Dabbler: valid as in it's a real, true XML **document** (with a single root node) - not a fragment. But since there is no schema in sight, it's cannot be said to be *valid* against any schema ...

Comment: marc_s: That's called well-formed.

Comment: The format, as stated above, is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your XML documents are well-formed, but they are different in content.
Note that line-breaks don't play a role here.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your documents are correct and readable

Answer (score 0):

You can easily transform the XML to your desired format. Use an XSLT stylesheet consisting of (a) an identity template, and (b) the rule

```
<xsl:template match="property">
  <xsl:element name="{@propertyName}">
   <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```